# programmatic password recovery from access 2007

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

i have an access 2003/2007 front end for a sql server database. the server to the sql server username is saved within the ACCDB file. another words the access front end has the password to the SQL SERVER database saved on it because i am accessing the tables in the sql server. i unfortunately forgot the password and am wondering if there is any programmatic way of recovering it?  thank you for any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying your ACCDB includes a link to a SQL Server table, and the UID and PWD were included in the connection string for that link, you can examine the TableDef Connect property.

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("YourTableLink").Connect
```

If you mean the password was saved by some other method, tell us how and where.